# Compute $\sup ||Ax||/||x||$ with constraint $||x|| > \delta$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-norms

Given an invertible, square matrix $A$, the induced 2-norm
$$||A|| := \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$
can be calculated easily by finding the largest singular value of $A$, assuming we're using the $L^2$ norm on vectors above.

But what about
$$||A||_\delta := \sup_{x : ||x|| > \delta} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$
for some positive $\delta$? How can we calculate this? Can we say something about where the supremum is achieved?

If it makes the problem easier, I'm only interested in computing this quantity for 3x3 matrices $A$ (but would appreciate a solution for general square matrices).

Since the fraction is invariant to scaling $x$, perhaps these two "norms" are equal?

Comment: The image of the unit sphere under a matrix A is an ellipsoid where the length of the semimajor axis is the largest singular value.  The image of a sphere is the same ellipsoid but multiplied by the radius of the sphere.  So the ratio remains the same for any radius delta > 0.

Comment: Thanks! So you agree that $||A||_\delta = ||A||$ then? Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @user334263 yes $\|A\|_{\delta} = \|A\|$ since $\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}=\frac{\|A(\delta v)\|}{\|\delta v\|}$ for all $\delta>0$ and $v\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $\left\|A\right\|_{\delta} \le \left\|A\right\|$, now let $x$ such that $$\frac{\left\|Ax\right\|}{\left\|x\right\|} \ge \left\|A\right\| - \epsilon$$ and $u = 2\delta \frac{x}{\left\|x\right\|}$, $\left\|u\right\| = 2\delta > \delta$ and $$\left\|A\right\|_{\delta} \ge \frac{\left\|Au\right\|}{\left\|u\right\|} = \frac{\left\|Ax\right\|}{\left\|x\right\|} \ge \left\|A\right\| -\epsilon$$